# Can anyone tell me how to reindex with Magento 2.0.2

Tags: magento2, error, reindex, magento-2.0.2

I am not very comfortable with command line in admin but when I run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` in the root directory I am getting

> Status:  404 Not Found X-Powered_By: PHP/5.5.33 content-type: 
>   text/html

Any suggestion on how to get reindex completed?  I am running Magento 2 on a virtual private server with Godaddy and the reindex does not seem to worl through the application.

Comment: check your file permissions

Comment: which file permissions? and what should they be set to?

Comment: [This topic](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html) explains permissions and ownership.

Answer (score 7):

if you are using windows then run this command in cmd

> C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>php.exe C:\wamp\www\Magento\www\bin\magento indexer:reindex

and if you want to reindex only one indexer then write following command:

> C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>php.exe C:\wamp\www\Magento\www\bin\magento indexer:reindex indexer_name.

where indexer_name can be found by typing following command :

> C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>php.exe C:\wamp\www\Magento\www\bin\magento indexer:info